# what's the use of QScopedValueRollback

Tags: qt

I saw this class QScopedValueRollback in Qt 4.8.1. Anyone can help to show a sample of usage of this new class? Sorry for my English. I don't quite understand why it's useful and needed from its doc. So I guess if anyone could provid me an sample code, I can understand it more clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand from the doc is.. It is used to automatically roll back a variable to the value outside the scope or to the one last committed..

```
void myfunc(int &val)
{ 
    // new scope
    QScopedValueRollBack newScope(val);
    val = 2;
    .
    .
    if (err)
        throw();
}

int val = 1;
myfunc(val);
// val = 1 again.. unless you call commit() after setting val inside new scope.. in which case val = 2 here.
```

Usefulness - can be used to revert state when an exception is thrown without needing to write try-catch blocks

Comment: thank you! Others think it's not like a question but you did answered it and your answer is indeed what I needed.